# Custom prompt message when saving file

Tags: custom-text-object, message

The default message displayed on the prompt when one saves a file is

```
"<file_name>" <nlines>L, <ncharacters>C written
```

and it remains in the prompt until another message is to be displayed.

I'd like to change this by using a custom message which should remain on the prompt for 1-2 seconds and then go away.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I believe one could do this with something like

```
augroup MyWriteMsg
  au!
  au BufWritePost echom 'my message'
augroup
```

Though you would want to use a timer to clear it. I’m not sure I see the value in doing that though, as it’s only more complexity for what (as far as *I* can see) is no benefit.

Comment: No you're right, there's no concrete benefit, I just like it better. Could you post the complete answer including a timer to clear the prompt?

Comment: @noibe from my phone, without vim docs, probably not. But you can read `:help timer` as a start

Comment: I guess it is smth like:
```
func! ClearMessage(timer_id) abort
 echo ''
endfunc
func! CustomSaveMessage() abort
 echo 'my message'
 call timer_start(1000, 'ClearMessage')
endfunc

augroup MyWriteMsg
  au!
  au BufWritePost * call CustomSaveMessage()
augroup END
``` 
But it wouldn't work as expected